Manually clear DynamoDB cache in UI
I'm wanting to know if it's possible to manually clear a DynamoDB table's cache in the UI, similar to how we can delete items from the table itself.
I know we can use Table.ClearTableCache() programatically, however I'm wanting to clear it manually via the UI for ease of use.
I'm trying to test some functionality where I need to expire the cache for a fresh set of data etc.
I had initially thought clearing down the table would do the trick but I've come to find that, as I'm adding the same primary key values back, it's picking up a cached version instead of adding new data.

What cache are you referring to?

I'm not entirely sure tbh. I've been trying to get fresh data from a downstream API by clearing my DB table and expecting that the data that then populates is correct etc. But it seems that there's almost a cached version being brought back. I'm repopulating with the same Primary Key values, so I assumed that there's some sort of cache in the table, and from what I've read it seems that there is?

There is no cache in a DynamoDB table unless you explicitly put a DAX cluster in front of it. If you're using something like APIGW or AppSync, make sure you're not caching there unnecessarily.

Cheers for the insight @LeeroyHannigan. I know there is an APIGW, but I'm certain that I've not got a cache in place there. I will do some digging, but it could just be the fault of a dependant API :D
